# Habilitar CORS en Jax rs( resteasy)

Tags: java, wildfly, cors, jax-rs

Estoy desarrollando un ejemplo de un rest api usando jax rs y llegue al punto de tener que agregar soporte para CORS y poder consumirlo desde una app en hecha en React, el otro dia publique el API REST en un servidor online y cuando lo consumo en React de manera local funciona, pero si intento consumirla desde una pagina de tipo [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) o [resttesttest](https://resttesttest.com/) no funciona.

Cabe mencionar que estoy usando como servidor es Wildfly 13, ya revise muchos diferentes ejemplo de filter pero ninguna me funciona en stackblitz o resttesttest.

API de prueba usando el filtro: [mi api](http://node42071-env-8457498.jl.serv.net.mx/api/)

Aqui esta mi filtro

```
@Provider
public class CorsResponseFilter implements Filter {

/**
 * Default constructor.
 */
public CorsResponseFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see Filter#destroy()
 */
public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/**
 * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
 */
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    System.out.println("CORSFilter HTTP Request: " + request.getMethod());

    // Authorize (allow) all domains to consume the content
    ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, OPTIONS, HEAD, PUT, POST");

    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    // For HTTP OPTIONS verb/method reply with ACCEPTED status code -- per CORS handshake
    if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
        return;
    }

    // pass the request along the filter chain
    chain.doFilter(request, servletResponse);
}

/**
 * @see Filter#init(FilterConfig)
 */
public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

El mensaje que obtengo en la consola del navegador es esta:

```
[Mixed-Content] The origin 'https://js-87ppru.stackblitz.io' was loaded in a secure context but tried to load an insecure  resource at 'http://node42071-env-8457498.jl.serv.net.mx/api'.
```

Aqui esta el ejemplo en stackblitz que uso https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-87ppru

Nota: No me interesa usar un proxy como el de heroku.

Comment: No te funciona... ¿qué error tienes? Dale a [edit] y añade un poco más de información sobre cómo falla, por favor

Comment: Funciona pero no en entornos tipo StackBlitz y no entiendo porque sucede eso, he probado con otras implementaciones como la que proporciona adam bien https://github.com/AdamBien/cors pero sigue funcionando igual, para mi aplication personal no tengo incoveniente pero quiero saber el motivo de que no funcione en esos entornos

Comment: Sigues sin decirnos cómo falla: cuál es el mensaje de error en la consola, qué aparece en la pestaña de Red del navegador (¿Aparecen los headers en la respuesta?)

Comment: Ya actualize la informacion con respecto a ello, creo ya vi el motivo porque sucede esto :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507566/mixed-content-blocked-when-running-an-http-ajax-operation-in-an-https-page

Comment: A esto me refería, los mensajes de error suelen ser bastante descriptivos, aunque a veces no los entendamos. Una vez que tenemos la información, la pregunta es correcta porque explica el escenario (y de ahí mi +1). Bienvenido a SOes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackblitz tiene una dirección  `https://stackblitz.com/edit/...`

Es decir, usa HTTP**S**.

El error te describe que 
desde un dominio HTTPS [no puedes hacer una llamada que requiera CORS a un servidor HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XDomainRequest#Security). Al revés tampoco funcionaría.